# Geospatial Index using MongoKit

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongokit

Is there a way to create geospatial indexes over fields in a [MongoKit](http://namlook.github.com/mongokit/) `Document`?

Right now I can't find any reference to do so using the `indexes` descriptor.

I would like to have something like

```
class Foo(Document):
    structure = {
        'location': {
            'lat': float,
            'lon': float
        }
    }
    indexes = [
        {
            'fields': ['location'],
            'type': '2d'
        }
    ]
```

Can I do this using [Pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was [documented](http://namlook.github.com/mongokit/indexes.html).

To create a geospatial index you need to:

```
class Foo(Document):
    structure = {
        'location': {
            'lat': float,
            'lon': float
        }
    }
    indexes = [
        {
            'fields': [('location', '2d'), ],
        }
    ]
```

I had to look at the [sources](https://github.com/namlook/mongokit/blob/master/mongokit/document.py#L421) to realize this.

Regards,

Comment: `If you use latitude and longitude as your coordinate system, always store longitude first. MongoDB’s 2d spherical index operators only recognize [ longitude, latitude] ordering.`
excerpt from here - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/#store-location-data